# How to completely remove unwanted branches and commits from Git repo

Tags: git

I have git repo with multiple applications inside(i know is a bad idea) and now I whant to create a new repo with single branch with commits only related to this single branch.

I whant to get smaller history, smaller repo size in MB on file system.
Total number of branches in 3K.

How to get this?

Comment: There are lots of documents online that discuss this topic, or at least something similar.  What have you looked at so far? What parts weren't clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do here is initialize a new git repository in a new location:

```
$ git init
```

And then on your existing repository, just push your branch to the new repository:

```
$ git push /c/your/new/repo/root your-branch-to-push
```

At that point git will dump the branch from the existing repository into the new (empty) repository.

Once you complete this (and verify the new repository), take whatever action on the source branch (i.e. if you don't need it on the original/source repo then delete it).

In the *new* repository, if you want to make the pushed branch renamed to `master`, for instance, you can rename it like this:

```
$ git branch -m your-old-branch-name master
```

Comment: Works for me thx, although beter with 'git gc --aggressive --prune=now' befoar push to remote.